# getAllDecorations is not a function

Tags: monaco-editor

I have managed to create line and in-line decorations and apply them to the editor, this is the code I am using to create the decorations:

```
editor.deltaDecorations([], myDecorations);
```

Now I am looking for a way to remove the decorations.

I tried the getAllDecorations as described here in the API documentation https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.itextmodelwithdecorations.html#getalldecorations, but when I try to use it like this:

```
var decs = editor.getAllDecorations();
```

I get the following error in the console of the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: editor.getAllDecorations is not a function(…)
```

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated! TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

getAllDecorations function is defined for *model* object, not *editor*, as you can see in the documentation

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.imodel.html#getalldecorations

so, you should use

```
editor.getModel().getAllDecorations();
```

Comment: I think this should be accepted as answer because it uses the official API and works as expected.